# Which TensorFlow object detection or image classification model suits the best to recognize details?

Tags: tensorflow, classification, object-detection

I want to retrain a pre-trained model with two classes of the same object with and without an extra part on the object. So it has to recognize a detail.
I am a beginner in this area and couldn't find a solution, maybe you even know a better solution than working with TensorFlow.

I hope you can help me and I am happy about any idea. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it a segmentation model or classification?

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad It is an image classification model MobileNet